# Can the_category display a post count?

Tags: categories

Is it possible for the_category to display a post count within a post.

Looks like Posted In: Category Name (3),Category Name (2) etc etc

Possible or not?

I would just use wp_list_categories but it needs to appear on a post by post basis like this post is posted in category x and y not just all of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

```
add_filter('get_the_categories', 'wpse50876_the_counter');

function wpse50876_the_counter($cats){
foreach($cats as $cat){
    $cat->cat_name = $cat->cat_name.'('.$cat->count.')';
}
return $cats;
}
```

Try it...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to hook `get_the_categories` to modify the `name` property of each category with a count of the number of objects with that count, which should be available in the `category_count` property (all of this assuming that I followed the code right).

Make sure that when you hook, you add the filter, do your call to `the_category()` then remove it immediately, as there may be other functions that you're using which depend on `get_the_category()`.

Comment: +1. I was going to suggest this - however, the filter would apply to all instances of `get_the_category`. This may not be an issue. Otherwise, you'll have to create your own function...

Comment: If you do something like `add_filter(); the_category(); remove_filter();` it doesn't apply it to all instances, just the one you want.

Comment: that's a good call :)

Comment: I've found myself using that method more and more recently...it really amplifies just how powerful wordpress hooks are.