# How can I change the tooltip in the_category?

Tags: categories, tooltip

My use of the_category works fine, but I want to change the tooltip, which says "View all posts in (category name)".

How can I change this tooltip?

I guess this might be something similar to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50876/can-the-category-display-a-post-count?rq=1).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the tooltip... but to what? Sorry my crystal ball isn't quite working today.

Here are some options you have:

- <strike>Change it in `wp-includes/category-template.php`</strike> but that's far from ideal since an update will overwrite this.
- You can add a function to your function.php file. For example if you want to remove it completely (since you didn't write how you want to change it):

  ```
  function categories_without_title_attribute() {
      $categories = wp_list_categories('echo=0');
      $categories = preg_replace('/title=\"(.*?)\"/','',$categories);
      echo $categories;
  }
  ```

Then of course use the fn to output your (modified) categories.

Comment: Thank you, I opted for the solution proposed below, which allows me to set the title I want without modifying master files.

Answer (score 2):

I used this solution instead, within my single.php file:

```
<?php
//categories loop

$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ', ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' .     esc_attr( sprintf( __( "%s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category-    >cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
    }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
?>
```